# Python stdout doesn't flush correctly after calling curses

Tags: python, stdout, flush, curses

I have a program that uses curses, and then returns to the main script for further processing. After it returns, my subsequent output to stdout does not appear until there's a large amount of it (e.g. thousands of bytes).

I've reduced the problem to a very simple program that fails reliably:

```
import curses
import time

curses.initscr()
curses.endwin()

print "Hello world!"
time.sleep(5)
```

If I comment out the two curses calls, the 'Hello world!' prints before the delay. If I put them in, it prints after the delay (when the script exits).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to flush output of Python print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: @jack.  nope. this relates to why the output buffer needs to be flushed in the first place

Comment: Ok, sorry. Just tried to help pointing the OP to something that could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `curses.endwin()` call "sets standard I/O back to normal"... which unfortunately means "buffered" (you could consider that a bug in `curses` and file the bug on Python's tracker).

To ensure standard-output is unbuffered,

```
import os

sys.stdout = os.fdopen(0, 'w', 0)
```

(You can put the `import os` at the start, or course; the reassignment of `sys.stdout` is meant to go right after the `endwin` call).

Comment: So does stdout begin life as unbuffered? I thought that's what the -u flag was for. But yes, this fix works, thanks.

Comment: What exactly "sets standard I/O back to normal"? I'm not seeing that in the Python docs, curses module source, or endwin man page (curs_initscr(3X)).

Answer (score 1):

Alex beat me to it (he knew, I had to figure it out) but I wrote this nifty context manager that you might be able to use.

```
import curses
import time
import os
import sys


class CursesStdout(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ = os.fdopen(sys.__stdout__.fileno(), 'w', 0)

with CursesStdout():
    curses.initscr()
    curses.endwin()


print "Hello world!"
time.sleep(2)
```

I modify `sys.__stdout__` directly because when you look at the source in `curses/__init__.py` you see that the `initscr` function passes that file descriptor to the C code and so I store that to be reset to normal.

Comment: This is nice too, but I can't use it because this project is on python 2.4. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

more clear way:

```
import sys
import curses

correct_stdout = sys.stdout    # remember correct

curses.initscr()
curses.endwin()

sys.stdout = correct_stdout    # restore correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that tis is system/library dependent. On my Windows machine (curses from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) it flushes and then sleeps, but on Linux it flushes after sleep. I think you can simply use: `sys.stdout.flush()` like:

```
print "Hello world!"
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(5)
```

(it may be better to make some kind of "print & flush" function)